# Chrome extension access to Active Directory credentials

Tags: google-chrome-extension, active-directory

I am working on some chrome extension, the extension address to some server. My boss wants the login process to be automatic without user interaction. He wants the extension to take the user's name and password from the user's computer and to auto login to the server with those credentials.

The extension is only html, Javascript...

Do you think it is possible to do that? Maybe with some hack or trick. Or a Chrome support?

Comment: Unless your boss puts the passwords - in **clear text** - into environment variables or some other insecure storage, any extension **won't be able** to retrieve the password for the user......

Comment: @marc_s I can write an `.exe` that write the credetials to to text file. can I read this file from the extension?

Comment: In standard Windows, ***there is NO way*** to "read out" a user's password. The only way to get it is by having the user enter it ...

Comment: @marc_s Then only domain name and user, without password

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement a one-time login. On the first login attempt, the server must issue a JWT token, then you can store the token inside chrome storage and each time the user opens the extension you can check for the existence of the JWT token on the storage and validate it for the login process.

Comment: But I need it to be fully automate. without login manually at all

Comment: Where the password is stored? Can you hardcode it inside your extension?

Comment: I can't hardcode the password, because the exttension can be downloaded from the chrom web store

Comment: Then where did you get the username and password? You mean the credentials of OS ?